# Why type deduction for auto specifier cares about only init field of the for-loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-deduction

The following example seems to be very easy and straightforward:

```
void ftest(size_t& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    size_t max = 5;
    for (auto i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        ftest(i);
}
```

but it won't compile (at least using VS2013) because the *i* is deduced as **int** and not as **size_t**. And the question is -- what is the point of *auto* in such for-loops if it can't rely on the conditional field? Would it be too much hard and time consuming if a compile analyze the whole statement and give expected result instead of what we're having now?

Comment: It would make the meaning of  `auto i = 0` context dependent and I can imagine that would cause all kinds of confusion.

Comment: Have you tried `for (auto i = 0lu; i < max; i++)` ? Maybe you should also check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505164/using-auto-in-loops-c)

Comment: A bit of reading: https://herbsutter.com/2015/01/14/reader-qa-auto-and-for-loop-index-variables/

Comment: There is nothing that requires the initialised variable(s) to even appear in the other parts of the `if` statement, so no way its compilation can be dependent on them.

Comment: "what is the point of auto in such for-loops?"  imho there is no point of using `auto` in that loop but it would be much easier to write `int` (or `size_t` if this is what you wanted)

Comment: IMO: yes, it would be too much to ask for the compiler to analyze your code so you can use auto. If the type is not clear, don't use auto in such situations. You can still use it everywhere else where it actually makes sense.

Comment: If you code like that, frankly, you're abusing the purpose of `auto` in the first place. It is intended to alleviate you from having to spam a **known** diatribe like `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>::const_iterator it = mymap.cbegin()` and instead deliver it free of charge, `auto it = mymap.cbegin();`.  In short, to answer your question "what is the point of auto in such for-loops" - there is no point to `auto` in a for loop as you've shown. Typing `size_t` takes two more keystrokes and eliminates any first-glance ambiguity imho.

Comment: "Would it be too much hard [...]" Yes, it would. This is not only the complexity of the implementation, but of the mental model you'd need to understand when reading the code, and when the proposed feature fails to do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @DragonRock: That assumes `std::is_same< std::size_t, unsigned long >`. Other reasonable choices would be `0u` and `0ull`, but of course none of those is portable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the type of variable is determined when declared (from its initializer), it has nothing do with how it will be used. If necessary type conversion would be considered. The rule is same as variables declared with type specified explicitly, [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is just helping you to deduce the type, it's not special.

Try to consider about this:

```
auto max = 5u;
for (auto i = 0; i < max; ++i)
//               ~~~~~~~~
//               i should be unsigned int, or max should be int ?
```

BTW: You could use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) if you want the type to be determined by the conditional field `max`:

```
for (decltype(max) i = 0; i < max; ++i)
```

Comment: You explain why `auto` is not context dependent in the general case, but in the case of a `for` loop statement (excluding its body), you cannot have multiple `auto` so the standard could have provided exceptions for this.

Comment: @Holt But how? What should the type be, the one used in the declaration, or the comparison?

Comment: @juanchopanza The type could be deduced with the same rules that apply to the ternary operator, which is already part of the standard. I am not saying this would be the way to do but it is one. I would personally prefer standard ranges function like the ones python have to use range-based on them ;)

Comment: @Holt The "ternary" is an expression, so `auto x = <expr>` works in the same way as `auto i = 0`. Here, we don't have an initialization expression involving the type used in the comparison. So, the new rules would have to be complicated, and I think they would only add confusion. A syntax for standard ranges would be a great thing to have. e.g. something like `for (auto i: [0..max])`

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree this would be confusing, but I don't think this would be complicated if you only have relational operators (but this is a too specific case... ). Having a custom syntax would be really nice but I would be already happy if the standard would provides standard functions to generate `range` structure that could be used in `for` loop, e.g. `for (auto i: range(0, max))` ;)

Comment: @Holt Consider the case where the predicate is independent of the initialization...
`size_t max = 5U;
char *buffer = new char[max];
for (auto i = 0; buffer != nullptr; ++i) {
  // ...
  if (i > max) {
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = nullptr;
  }
}`

In this sample, the specification is well defined.  Since `0` is an `int` so is `i`.  However, if we tried to use predicate to tell us what `i` should be, then we'd get either `char*` or `nullptr_t`.  Neither of those is an acceptable choice in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Keyword `auto` has nothing do with the rest of `for` statement, neither it knows about it. If you say it should infer from `max`, you are saying *delay the type deduction*, which won't comply with the `auto` type-inference rules.

Additionally, what about this?

```
  size_t max = 5;
  short min = 1;
  for (auto i = 0; i < max && i > min; ++i)
```

Should it infer to `short` or `size_t` ? You cannot make compiler to *read your mind!*

Also, such delayed inference rules (if any) would complicate templates meta-programming.

Comment: I am not sure this would be that complicated actually - This could comes down to having to compute the type for `auto t = true ? 0 : (true ? max : min))`, which is `size_t` in this case. If there are only operators involved with the variable `i`, this can be deduced quite easily. But as I mentioned in my answer, this is a specific case, and the standard does not "care" about specific cases.

Comment: @Holt: Ok, assume `template<typename T> T max(T); for (auto i = 0; i < max(i); ++i`)`. Now the type of `i` would depend on the type of `max(i)` which obviously depends on the type of `i` ! Realistically, the conditional expression of the for-loop must be (convertible) to `bool`, and you cannot decently describe how `auto` should deduce a type from **part of**  a random boolean expression.

Comment: @MSalters See my answer which exactly expose this issue. My points was simply that "simple" expression involving only relational operators could be deduced, but it is a very specific cases (and the standard is not gonna makes rule for such cases).

Answer (score 6):

You are actually providing a very simple case, where the condition is a simple `i < max` where the type of `max` is known. The standard tries to provide rules that apply in all cases, now let's consider this:

```
bool f(int);
bool f(size_t);

for (auto i = 0; f(i); ++i) { }
```

If the type of `i` was dependent on the conditional expression in the `for` loop, your compiler will probably not be happy.

Also, Herb Sutter as a small post on its blog about this issue actually: https://herbsutter.com/2015/01/14/reader-qa-auto-and-for-loop-index-variables/