# Auto failed for vector size

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, auto

I am trying use `auto` to infer the type.

```
for (auto i = remaining_group.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

I get very large number like 18446744073709534800 which is not expected. When I change `auto` to `int` it is the number I expected between 0 and 39.

Is there any reason `auto` will fail here?

`remaining_group`'s type is a `std::vector<lidar_point>` and `lidar_point` is struct like:

```
struct LidarPoint {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  uint8_t field1;
  double field2;
  uint8_t field3;
  uint16_t field4;
}
```

Comment: How is `remainug_group` defined? Also - maybe the size is 0?

Comment: what type `size()` returns?

Comment: If `size` is unsigned then condition `i >= 0` is always true and you eventually get an integer underflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using auto in loops c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505164/using-auto-in-loops-c)

Comment: It only takes 2 more chars to write `size_t` instead of `auto` but the explicitness it brings is well worth it

Comment: What compiler are you using that didn't give a warning for your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `auto` the type of `i` would be [`std::vector::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types), which is an unsigned integer type. That means the condition `i >= 0;` would be always `true`, and if [overflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) happens you'll get some large numbers.

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>    where n is the number of bits in that particular integer. E.g. for `unsigned int`, adding one to `UINT_MAX` gives `​0`​, and subtracting one from ​`0`​ gives `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right answer. Really need to be careful using auto in this case!

Comment: @songyuanyao • the static cast should not including the `- 1` part.  Consider what happens when remaining_group is empty, so has size 0.

Comment: @Eljay Correct.

Comment: @Alex Here's a wordy workaround if you stick to `auto`, `auto i = static_cast<int>(remaining_group.size()) - 1`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I didn't get it; the type of `i` is still an unsigned integer type? [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YoPj3VD3A0Mu35eK)

Comment: @songyuanyao hm, interesting, I found compiler bug

Answer (score 1):

Simple reproduction of problem:

```
#include <iostream>

size_t size()  {return 1;}

int main() {
   for (auto i = size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
   }
}
```

`size()` got type `size_t` and literal constant `1` would be promoted to `size_t`, in result `auto` would become `size_t`, which cannot be less than zero, resulting in infinite  loop and underflow of `i`.

Comment: Oh, man, integer promotion. I would have expected the final type so be signed, but ... promotion rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a reverse index loop, use [`operator -->`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642035/2683574)

When you write a normal index loop, you write it with `0`, `size`, and `<`.

When you write a normal reverse index loop, things become a bit wonky: you need `size - 1`, `>=`, `0`, and you can't use *unsigned* index, because unsigned `i` is always `>= 0` so your check `i >= 0` always returns `true`, your loop could run forever.

With fake operator "goes to", you can use `0`, `size`, and `>` to write the reverse index loop, and it doesn't matter if `i` is signed or unsigned:

```
for (auto i = a.size(); i --> 0; ) //or just i--, or i --> 1, i --> 10...
    std::cout << i << ' ';
```