# Get to STL container's size_type using a variable

Tags: c++, loops, auto

I want to write index-based for loops in a simple way. Since my code has to run in 32 and 64 bit, I get lots of warnings about implicit conversions because I usually use 32 bit integers but the STL uses 64 bit integers in 64 bit.

```
std::vector<MyClass> c;
for (FOO ui = 0, uiEnd = c.size(); ui < uiEnd; ++ui){...}
```

- `FOO = unsigned int` works on 32 bit but generates warnings on 64 bit.
- `FOO = size_t` works on 32 and 64 bit but is not entirely correct because the Standard does not require `std::vector<MyClass>::size_type == size_t`.
- `FOO = auto` does not work (which is quite unfortunate) because it sets the type for each variable individually, so the type of the literal 0 (or 0UL or whatever) which differs from c.size() (in 32 or 64 bit, the type of c.size() can differ, so I cannot write the correct literal).
- `for (auto uiEnd = c.size(), ui = 0*uiEnd; ui < uiEnd; ++ui){...}` works by expressing 0 with the correct type but is obscure.
- `FOO = decltype(c.size())` works but I find it obscure.
- `FOO = std::vector<MyClass>::size_type` works but I find it tedious to repeat the type of the container.

I would prefer something like `FOO = c::size_type`, which clearly expresses what is happening. But is it possible to get the `size_type` of `std::vector<MyClass>` using only the variable `c`? I tried the following things without success:

- `c::size_type`
- `typeid(c)::size_type`
- `decltype(c)::size_type`

Comment: Different but related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505164/using-auto-in-loops-c

Comment: What about `auto uiEnd = c.size(), ui = 0;`? No idea, just throwing it out there.

Comment: `decltype(c)::size_type` should, and indeed [*does* work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e6677f628d2e8ba). If it didn't for you, then I suspect your example is too simplified to express why it didn't.

Comment: I'd still use `std::size_t`. If you find a `vector` where `size_type` isn't  `size_t` it is very likely using a smaller type than `size_t`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I am using Visual Studio 2010. It seems that decltype() support is incomplete. I get an error that ::size_type is undefined, as if there was a space between the decltype and the ::size_type. If that is the case, I will opt for decltype(c.size()) until I can update my compiler. Thank you for your remark!

Comment: for range or iterator might avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas you might use:

```
std::vector<MyClass> c;

for (decltype(c)::size_type ui = 0, uiEnd = c.size(); ui < uiEnd; ++ui){...}
```

I would use:

```
std::vector<MyClass> c;

std::size_t index = 0; // as you want index too
for (auto& myclass : c){...; ++index;}
```

And even in C++20:

```
std::vector<MyClass> c;

for (std::size_t index = 0; auto& myclass : c){...; ++index;}
```

[ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) has `enumerate` view:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;

for (const auto& [index, myclass] : v | ranges::v3::views::enumerate) {
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/43e7x5rqn)

Comment: This will be nicer in C++20, where (afaik?) we'll get to initialise another variable when starting a range-based `for` loop, so that `index` won't leak scope anymore.

Comment: @underscore_d: Added c++20 version.Not fan of that new syntax which makes c++ even more complicated for no real benefit (with short functions, scope is not a issue) (XY solution IMO).

Comment: Continue will skip the increment, which is a source of unexpected errors.